# How to obtain all OIDs from all MIBs

Tags: parsing, snmp, oid, mib

I would like obtain a list of all OIDs in the MIBs that are loaded on a manager and display it to users so that they can choose which MIB object to perform the GET/SET request. I would also like to obtain the syntax and max-access of the object. I'm programming using C++. I want to parse the MIBs to obtain the OIDs, not use snmpwalk. I am trying to use the Net-SNMP MIB_API. I've looked at the manual page but am not clear of how to use the functions to achieve what I want to do.

I see that read_all_mibs() is already called when we call init_mib(). That means I don't need to call read_all_mibs() again, right? Could anyone please guide on what is the next step after init_mib() that I should do.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the `apps/snmptranslate.c` file for an example of how to walk the loaded mib tree to get information like the syntax and max-access details.

And, no, if you call `init_snmp()` or `init_mib()` you don't need to call `read_all_mibs()`